# How to generate columns in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have following table in sql server.

```
ID ,EventID ,EventDate ,Title ,Type
```

Now I want to make query in below logic.
if user enter fromdate and todate. Here event are weekly or biweekly.
so let say fromdate '03/01/2016' to '03/31/2016 and type biweekly.  Means columns are every biweekly.

so I want to generate query like.

3/1/2016 to 3/15/2016 | 3/16/2016 to 3/30/2016-these 2 biweekly are columns

if I pass so let say fromdate '03/01/2016' to '03/31/2016 and type weekly.

then columns should like every week

```
3/1/2016 to 3/8/2016 | 3/9/2016 to 3/16/2016 |3/17/2016 to 3/24/2016 and so on to till end date(To).
```

and rows of above output is Title.

How can this possible in sql server?

Comment: Look up dynamic PIVOT. You will need to make this dynamic to handle the varying number of columns and also to handle the dynamic column names.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get biweekly/weekly value. Let's say the user selects weekly. The value would be 7.
2. Use a loop to generate the columns. For instance, column1 would be the StartDate_to_EndDate. The StartDate would be the value the user entered. The EndDate would be the StartDate + 7 days(The value from #1 above)
3. Loop Through to get the second column etc etc (until the EndDate the user specified)